# pyspark 3.4.2 unable to read csv file with SparkContext

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyterhub

i am running spark remote kernel on jupyterhub but failling to read csv file on both executer and driver cluster node,i am able to add file but failing to read csv with below error.

pyspark 3.4.2 command from jupyterhub3.2.2 notebook

```
sc = pyspark.SparkContext.getOrCreate()
sc.addFile('file://' + '/opt/spark-3.4.2-bin-hadoop3/work-dir/stock-market-india/FullDataCsv/ZEEL__EQ__NSE__NSE__MINUTE.csv')
fdd = sc.textFile('ZEEL__EQ__NSE__NSE__MINUTE.csv')
fdd.collect()
```

i can see temp files under below dir in both executer pods

```
#ll /var/data/spark-13acd4aa-2344-4b00-800a-daa4771b7d1f/spark-2c886ade-ac67-4fa2-ba29-e5e4844845fe
-rw-r--r-- 1 jovyan users 21429281 Feb  5 08:40 1831154171707122432750_cache
-rw-r--r-- 1 jovyan users        0 Feb  5 08:40 1831154171707122432750_lock
-rw-r--r-- 1 jovyan users 21889857 Feb  5 05:46 20226180011707111990941_cache
-rw-r--r-- 1 jovyan users        0 Feb  5 05:46 20226180011707111990941_lock
```

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: file:/opt/spark-3.4.2-bin-hadoop3/work-dir/ZEEL__EQ__NSE__NSE__MINUTE.csv
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:304)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:244)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:332)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:208)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$partitions$2(RDD.scala:291)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$partitions$2(RDD.scala:291)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2328)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$collect$1(RDD.scala:1019)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:405)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:1018)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:374)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Input path does not exist: file:/opt/spark-3.4.2-bin-hadoop3/work-dir/ZEEL__EQ__NSE__NSE__MINUTE.csv
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:278)
    ... 30 more
```

/opt/spark-3.4.2-bin-hadoop3/work-dir/ZEEL__EQ__NSE__NSE__MINUTE.csv   this file is available on both executer on same path.

am i missing or doing anything wrong?

Comment: You can move that file to hdfs or cloud location and then read it using full path ? if it is local you can put that file in some temp location and pass that path to spark.